# Modest-py python library for FMU parameter estimation using FMPy library instead of PyFMI library

Tags: python, pyfmi

I am using [modest-py](https://github.com/sdu-cfei/modest-py) python library for [FMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_Mock-up_Interface) functional mockup units parameter estimation.

By default modest-py is using [PyFMI](https://github.com/modelon-community/PyFMI) for handling the FMU files.

I need to use [FMPy](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) library inside of modest-py to do the same, in other words swap the libraries.

Here is the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/sdu-cfei/modest-py/issues/52) on GitHub.

Probably it can be solved by smart applying the adapter pattern, but I do not see how.

Has anybody done it before?

Comment: FMPy support has been added in [PR 62](https://github.com/sdu-cfei/modest-py/pull/62).